# Search Everywhere for comments in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, full-text-search

PyCharm's Search Everywhere functionality easily allows the user to search everywhere for source code in every file of the project. However it is not able to search for comments, is there a way around that problem?

[image: animation of search everywhere in IDE]

I usually leave important comments of lessons learned or links to Stack Overflow containing helpful code, and would love a way to easily search for these comments, when I forget where I wrote them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Is a project wide text search. I think there's an option button to search comments.

Comment: Thanks, nice alternative, an addition  of comments to "Search Everywhere" would be the ideal, but "Find in Path" has some useful settings as well.

Comment: You can file a feature request to pycharm if you really want it, but source files are more useful to find in my opinion

Comment: Indeed, the feature should be optional

Comment: Feature Requested: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/647918?flash_digest=985ae70e358284bb332c980a1e1cb4fddd485cc7

Answer (score 5):

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> you need this button:

[image: screenshot of Find in Path dialogue]

And select `in comments`.

Answer (score 3):

I once had a problem with `Search Everywhere` or `Find in Path`(`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F` for windows) i.e. project wide search for a django project in Pycharm Professional 2020.1.
Although filter was selected as `Anywhere`, still some were not being found in the project files which were actually there.

But after invalidating caches & restarting like the picture, everything was fine.

First select `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` in `File` menu.
[image]

Then click `Invalidate and Restart` in the `Invalidate Caches` popup window.
[image]